# Formatting header text in nested gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

[image]

I have created a nested gridview as shown in the picture. The header of the child grid is repeated. Is there anyway I can add the child gridview's headers inline with the parent gridview?.Something like I have given below. [image]

Comment: Try removing the child gridview header and add the required headings to the parent gridview with fixed spacing (possible only if the column lengths are fixed)

Comment: @Nalaka526 Thanks can you put this as an answer please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the child gridview header and add the required headings to the parent gridview with fixed spacing (possible only if the column lengths are fixed)